# Promisses issue validating a user using password.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, passport.js, es6-promise

I'm trying to create validation using passport.js and ES6

Here is my validation function

```
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
    function(login, password, callback) {
        User.findOne({ login: login }).select('_id roles')
            .populate({ path: 'roles', select: 'name userPermissionsBitMask' })
            .then(entity => checkIfUserHasAdminPerms(entity))
            .then(varifyPassword(password, '$2a$05$F/QwjSo/DImWaUzv8nl4g.LqPKAcXhiBaiXGbRIN/k44dgD5nZ/9C'))
            .then(() => callback(null, true))
            .catch(err => callback(null, false));
    }))
```

`$2a$05$F/QwjSo/DImWaUzv8nl4g.LqPKAcXhiBaiXGbRIN/k44dgD5nZ/9C is bcrypt` hash for `1234 password`.

Here functions I use during validation.

```
function checkIfUserHasAdminPerms(roles) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let foundRole = _.find(entity.roles, role => role.name === 'am')
    foundRole ? resolve(foundRole) : reject(new HttpError(NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE, 'Not found'));
    });
}

function varifyPassword(password, hash) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        bcrypt.compare(password, hash, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            return result ? resolve() : reject();
        })
    );
}
```

The idea is to find user in database with role name am, if this role is presented, try to validate username/passport, if not - stop validation on this step.
Seems to me I have done something wrong with promises as if I type 123 password route works as if validation passed successfully, but it shouldn't be so, as password is incorrect. I've checked the `varifyPassword` function and in case of password 123 result is false.

Comment: It's not the problem, but `let role = _.find(roles, role => role.name === 'am')` followed by `role.name === 'am' ? resolve(role) : reject(...)` is almost certainly wrong, as `role` will be `undefined` if it's not found, throwing an error on `role.name`.

Comment: I've fixed this 
let foundRole = _.find(entity.roles, role => role.name === 'am')
        foundRole ? resolve(foundRole) : reject(new HttpError(NOT_FOUND_ERROR_CODE, 'Not found'));

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong.

```
.then(() = > varifyPassword(password, '$2a$05$F/QwjSo/DImWaUzv8nl4g.LqPKAcXhiBaiXGbRIN/k44dgD5nZ/9C'))
            .then(() => callback(null, true))
            .catch(err => callback(null, false));
```

Should look like this